# IndexOf doesn't work correctly with object which contain array

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, listener, indexof

I have a the next code:

```
function insertIfNotThere(array, item) {
    /* Push the new element everytime: because return -1 */
    if (array.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        array.push(item);
    }
    /*But this log shows 1, 2, 3 and so on...*/
    console.log(array.length);

}

function EventManager(target) {
    var target = target || window, events = {};
    this.observe = function(eventName, cb) {
        if (events[eventName]){
           /* This insert the new event everytime: indexOf doesn't work... */
           insertIfNotThere(events[eventName], cb);
        }else{
           events[eventName] = []; events[eventName].push(cb);
        }
        return target;
    };

    this.fire = function(eventName) {
        if (!events[eventName]) return false;
        for (var i = 0; i < events[eventName].length; i++) {
        events[eventName][i].apply(target, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        }
    };
}
```

I use "insertIfNotThere" method for checking if the element with the content indicated exist. But... It push the element ever... I don't know what's happening...

I created the event with a button: if I click several times in this, duplicate the elements...

Comment: what type is `cb`? Is it an object?

Comment: Is a function (cb=callback). I want to manage custom events.
I use it as follow: registerHandler('mycustomevent', function() {
            console.log("Detect");
        });

Comment: So, it is an object (functions are objects).

Comment: ¡Ahm! Sorry, I don't knew it. :) It's an object... IndexOf doesn't work with objects?

Comment: Please post your edit as an answer rather than putting it in the question. We encourage self-answered questions here so long as they're good questions.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue as follow:

```
function indexOf(array, item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].toString() === item.toString()) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This method works fine with my code.

Comment: Did you just wrote your own indexOf because the original array.infexOf doesnt work with objects well? What was the reasoning?